# Как прикрепить изображение к методу Wall.Post в vkNet

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

Непонятно как заполняется/работает *attachments* в методе *Wall.Post*

Моя первоначальная и главная задача заключается в добавлении изображения к посту вконтакте.

```
private void WallPost()
    {
        List<MediaAttachment> attachments = new List<MediaAttachment>();

        attachments.Add(new Photo
        {
            ?????
        });

        WallPostParams postParams = new WallPostParams
        {
            Attachments = attachments,
            Message = ---,
            OwnerId = ---,
            FromGroup = true
        };
    }

public void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WallPost();
    }
```

Comment: В FAQ все есть - https://github.com/vknet/vk/wiki/FAQ , только вместо MessagesParams записывается в WallPostParams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился с помощью FAQ (github.com/vknet/vk/wiki/FAQ).
Правильные параметры:

```
private void WallPost()
    {
        var albumid = ---;
        var photos = api.Photo.Get(new PhotoGetParams
        {
            AlbumId = PhotoAlbumType.Id(albumid),
            OwnerId = ---
        });

        WallPostParams postParams = new WallPostParams
        {
            Attachments = photos,
            Message = "text",
            OwnerId = ---,   
        };
    }
```

*Отдельное спасибо за подсказку пользователю PsiHamster*